# How to search a String and Add new String below the result?

Tags: regex, replace

I want to add a new String `NEWSTRING` under (next line) the String `EXISTINGSTRING` which is present in multiple JSP files in my project. I am able to search `EXISTINGSTRING` using a regular expression. Is there any way to add `NEWSTRING` under `EXISTINGSTRING` in all JSP files using replace functionality or some other way? I am using IBM RAD to do this search.

Comment: It would be good if you'd provide pattern, sample input and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with replace.
When searching for EXISTINGSTRING make this line a group

```
pattern = "^(.*EXISTINGSTRING.*)$" // this will identify line with searched string
```

than replace it with group1 + NewLine + NEWSTRING

```
replaceWith = "$1\nNEWSTRING"
```

Comment: Perfect! I had two groups in a search pattern. I used replace pattern as "$1$2\nNEWSTRING" and that worked for me.